# How to create an activator.createinstance() with expressions?

Tags: c#, expression, createinstance

The method `activator.CreateInstance()` is known to be slow. Direct calling var `X = new Class()` is the quickest. But `Expression.New()` compiled is also very quick.

But I don't know how to let it work with a variable number of params in the constructor.

So my question is: how should I create a `func<Type, object[], object>` with expressions to create an instance, where the object array contains the parameters for the constructor.

The end goal is to do this:

```
var a = Creator(typeof(ClassA),new[]{1,2}); //ClassA has 2 params
var b = Creator(typeof(ClassB),new[]{"some text"}); //ClassB has only 1 param
```

I have read in the `Expression.New()` there is a possibility to have multiple params.

Comment: What are you trying to do or try to build? What part of your code are you trying to abstract/generalize? How do you define "slow" in regards of `activator.CreateInstance()` or how/why is it relevant in your case?

Comment: Please check this: https://andrewlock.net/benchmarking-4-reflection-methods-for-calling-a-constructor-in-dotnet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above question in a comment can bring some light too, but regarding `Expression.New` and parameters:

```
    public class Dummy
    {
        public Dummy(int a) => A = a;
        public int A;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var classTypeInfo = typeof(Dummy).GetTypeInfo();
        var constructorInfo = classTypeInfo.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).First();
        var parameters = constructorInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => Expression.Parameter(p.ParameterType, p.Name)).ToArray();
        var body = Expression.New(constructorInfo, parameters);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, parameters);
        var @delegate = lambda.Compile();
        // case 1
        var func = (Func<int, Dummy>)@delegate;
        var value = func(10);

        // case 2
        var value = (Dummy)@delegate.DynamicInvoke(10);

        Console.WriteLine(value.A);  // 10
    }
```

Comment: But this also work like this: func<params object [ ], object>? The constructor has for example 4 params. So the caller will execute this like: func(a, b, c, d)

Comment: Maybe to explain it more: there are unknown number of classes, which has unknown number of params. The caller knows his set of classes has a fix X number of params.

Comment: You can use `params` for arguments via DynamicInvoke method